# How do I use multiple fonts ie a composite font in HexaPDF

Tags: ruby, fonts, emoji, truetype, glyphicons

Our users are giving us Emoji and a lot of other weird characters and the built-in Helvetica can't handle it. Neither can Google's Noto fonts by themselves - I need to figure out how to declare the Noto Font Family in HexaPDF and I can't figure out how to do that with the given documentation. OpenSans was an improvement, but I still want more glyph coverage than that.

Update:

I used this method to set the font:

```
def self.pdf_summary_font
  @@pdf_summary_font ||= File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 
'OpenSansEmoji.ttf'), 'r')
end
canvas = page.canvas(type: :overlay)
canvas.font(self.class.pdf_summary_font, size: 10)
```

However, no Noto font ever worked with this - I would get errors like "Missing glyph - 'A'"

The best I could do was to use OpenSansEmoji, and replace missing glyphs with the following block:

```
  begin
    style = HexaPDF::Layout::Style.new(font: canvas.font, fill_color: color, stroke_color: color, align: :left, valign: :center)
    fragment = HexaPDF::Layout::TextFragment.create(str, style)
    layouter = HexaPDF::Layout::TextLayouter.new(style)
    layouter.fit([fragment], w, h).draw(canvas, x1, y2)
  rescue HexaPDF::Error => e
    if e.message.include?('Glyph for')
      glyph =  e.message.match(/\{(.*?)\}/).captures.first
      str = str.grapheme_clusters.map do |char|
        if char.dump.include?(glyph)
          "\u{FFFD}"
        else
          char
        end
      end.join

      retry
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/documentation/reference/api/HexaPDF/index.html and the configuration option "font_map". This allows you to declare any TrueType file and use it.

You could also use the path to the font file directly with the `Canvas#font` method.

If you need to cover a wide array of characters you need to use a single font that covers all of them, one of [the fonts included in this ZIP file](https://noto-website-2.storage.googleapis.com/pkgs/NotoSans-hinted.zip) should probably work (Google says 582 languages, 237 regions included).

Comment: @getalong, thanks for your reply, any input on the solution I posted?

Comment: @EntaroAdun Could you provide a sample string that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @EntaroAdun Also have a look at the 'font.on_missing_glyph" configuration option - see https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/documentation/reference/api/HexaPDF/index.html . This allows you to specify custom behaviour for missing glyphs.